# Do tile floors have transition joints at the entry to each room?

Tags: floor

Hello I have a question regarding setting down some tiles.  I tried researching the topic but I was unsuccessful. I posted a picture of the rooms that i will be setting down tiles.  Which consist of 4 rooms and 2 bath rooms. I was wondering, when you start a room do you only lay the tiles down in that room and cut it off at the door way Or do you allow it to transitions in to the hallways/rooms?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Nice diagram, but are those supposed to be the tiles? They're enormous, and irregular, which seems confusing.

Comment: I'd surmise that we're looking at a plan view of "multiple rooms".

Comment: You transition into the hallways/rooms. No cutting the tile off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, tile layout flows from one room to the next. It would be visually disruptive to have extra joints at each doorway. You'll want to establish a single reference line, along with a perpendicular line at an appropriate location, and work from those.

If you exceed say 30 feet in length it may be prudent to install an [expansion gap](https://www.ceramictilefoundation.org/blog/next-ask-scott-expansion-joints-who-needs-them). You'll want to talk with your tile supplier about that. We don't know where you live, what your subfloor situation is, or what you're installing.

Comment: Tile is just like hard wood no transition is needed if it is all the same height. Even a pattern change at most I put in a divider strip so it looks like a clean change.+

Answer (score 0):

We had our whole 2000 sq ft house tiled in the same 18x18" porcelain tiles. (One of the two bathrooms retained tile from a previous remodeling.) The pattern flows uninterrupted from one room to the next.

I have since wondered if this is the best tiling pattern because one cannot tile each room symmetrically.

I am especially disappointed in the result in a long L shaped hallway in the center of the house. A hallway especially should be tiled symmetrically.

The solution would be to have a transition piece in each doorway so that a new tiling pattern could be established in each room. This might be in conjunction with a contrasting wall border tiling in some rooms.

This design choice must be covered in treatises on tiling.

**EDIT**

By a "transition piece" I would not necessarily mean a raised threshold. I was thinking of narrower tiles (maybe contrasting or maybe not) that would be wide enough to break the pattern.

Comment: Fair point, but I wouldn't create shifts in the pattern for that reason, which would be _more_ disruptive to the eye. Typically you'd just make a decision about where symmetry is most important. It doesn't matter in most rooms because furniture and other visual distractions eliminate the problem. I'd probably have started layout from the hallways you mention.